# how to answer to all interactive dialogs and non-dialog questions

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, kernel

i want to run this command on ubuntu 18.04 from node js code so i can't answer to prompts and i should call it once

> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04

with bellow trick i've done it

> printf '\n' | sudo apt-get install --install-recommends
> linux-generic-hwe-18.04

but then i get a dialog question that second option is selected but my answer is first option AKA "install the package maintainer's version"
below trick doesn't work on it

```
┌─────────────────────────────────┤  ├─────────────────────────────────┐
│ A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version   │
│ installed currently has been locally modified.                       │
│                                                                      │
│ What would you like to do about menu.lst?                            │
│                                                                      │
│     install the package maintainer's version                         │
│     keep the local version currently installed                       │
│     show the differences between the versions                        │
│     show a side-by-side difference between the versions              │
│     show a 3-way difference between available versions               │
│     do a 3-way merge between available versions (experimental)       │
│     start a new shell to examine the situation                       │
│                                                                      │
│                                                                      │
│                                <Ok>                                  │
│                                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

none of below works

> printf '\n1\n' | sudo apt-get install --install-recommends
> linux-generic-hwe-18.04 printf '\n\n' | sudo apt-get install
> --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04

also i've tried many methods like bellow but it didn't work

> sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o
> Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"
> dist-upgrade

i'm encountering with these kind of questions many time for example on libssl questions
please tell me how can i answer to this kind of questions ?
i want to answer to all of the questions in the first place that i run the command

Comment: You can try by running `yes | __your-command__ ` where "__your-command__" is the command you want to run with all (yes) answers to prompt

Comment: it just answers yes to regular questions not dialogs

Answer (score 2):

Dpkg actually does offer a method of automating dialog questions answering, and is very popular when preseeding an installation (mostly ubuntu server, though not supported by the new installer), as such installers tend to have a vast amount of menus and menu options.

#### What is a debconf file ?

---

A **debconf** (debian configuration) file, **also known as seed file**, is a file listing parameters and questions asked by the installer (word by word, as is) and our answers to them. If a question is missing or answered by an unsupported answer - a default value will be chosen (if possible).

Every package has a **configuration list**, even if no questions were asked at the process of installation and default values were used. When reinstalling a package and not specifying any new configurations, the already known ones by the machine are used.
**Note:** debconf files do not actually configure the packages, they simply hold a set of questions and answer values used by the installer.

#### How can we view or create package debconf selections ?

---

- To list all selections made for every installed package, simply use `debconf-get-selections`.
- To list a specific package, use `debconf-get-selections |grep '<my_package_name>'`.
- To change an existing answer's value with another value or add new selections from the command line, use `debconf-set-selections '<my_package_selection_stanza>'`.
- To change or add a values from a file, use `debconf-set-selections '<my_file_location>'`.

See manual pages for more information: [debconf-get-selections(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/debconf-get-selections.1.html), [debconf-set-selections(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html).

It is usually hard to come up with the correct full selection list, and a very good method is to first install a package, dump its selections to a file, edit the relevant selections and set the new selections from the file.
You may also pipe a string or a file content to the set command:

```
echo "some selection" |debconf-set-selections
```

#### Understanding debconf syntax:

---

Here is an example of two package debconf selections, one is for lightdm (an ubuntu display manager), and a few stanzas from grub selections:

```
$debconf-get-selections |grep lightdm
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager   select   lightdm
lightdm lightdm/daemon_name   string   /usr/sbin/lightdm

$debconf-get-selections |grep grub-pc
grub-pc grub-pc/chainload_from_menu.list boolean true
grub-pc grub-pc/timeout string 10
grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices multiselect
```

As we can see, the syntax is very intuitive: the first part is the package name, followed by a '/' and a question/configuration name. Afterwords comes a method of answering and an answer.

#### Injecting debconf selections and package reconfiguration

---

`debconf-set-selections` command updated the debconf database stored in the OS. It is possible to set a selection list prior to new package installations, and those will be used.
For packages already installed, there is no need for a purge. Simple use `dpkg-reconfigure '<my_package_name>'` after applying the new selections.

You may also define a debconf level, allowing only some questions / confirmation prompts to appear and answered by you, or define that non but critical questions shall be asked:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -p '<level>' '<my_package_name>'
```

Available levels are: low, medium, high or critical. More information about debconf here: [debianwiki/debconf](https://wiki.debian.org/debconf).
If you would like to absolutely disable any dialog (recommended only when your selections fit exactly as you intended), use the Noninteractive option: `dpkg-reconfigure --frontend Noninteractive '<package_name>'`.

Comment: Please change Noninteractive to noninteractive at the end, because of the error message "debconf: Please do not capitalize the first letter of the debconf frontend."

@AskUbuntu: frustrating feature doesn't allow corrections; how to edit 6 characters when one character edit is needed? -duh-

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programatically answer to prompts from an interactive program, you should use `expect`. Install the `expect` package and write a script that runs your program and answers prompts. The general layout of the script will be as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn <command_to_run>
expect <something_that_should_appear_on_screen>
send <keys_that_should_be_sent_to_program>
expect <something_that_should_appear_on_screen>
send <keys_that_should_be_sent_to_program>
expect <something_that_should_appear_on_screen>
send <keys_that_should_be_sent_to_program>
...
expect <something_that_should_appear_at_the_very_end>
exit
```

It takes some practice to correctly use expect, but once you get used to it, it is an extremely useful tool.